# Spring Roo unable to generate Selenium tests because of Xerces error

Tags: java, dom, classpath, xerces, spring-roo

After watching [Roo Google IO](http://www.youtube.com/googledevelopers#p/c/02292AD8CFFE1349/8/GQHlhIIxCIc), I decided to try it out using [this tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html), but I'm getting stuck when trying to create Selenium tests.

```
~.web roo> selenium test --controller ~.web.PizzaOrderController
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-pizzaorder.xhtml
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-suite.xhtml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-suite.xhtml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-pizzaorder.xhtml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredCommentImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
```

A person at [this forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5336340) suggested removing Xerces from the classpath because Java 6 has its own XML parser based on **Xerces**. However, I haven't come across a clear way to remove something from the **classpath**, only [setting it](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html) (which I think would be tedious each time).

Does anyone know of a clear way to **remove jars from the classpath**? Has anyone encountered this Roo problem before and solved it another way?

---

### UPDATE

As requested, here is the more verbose output:

```
roo> development mode
Development mode set to true
roo> selenium test --controller ~.web.PizzaOrderController
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-pizzaorder.xhtml
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-suite.xhtml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-suite.xhtml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium/test-pizzaorder.xhtml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/selenium
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredCommentImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredCommentImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.web.menu.MenuOperationsImpl.addMenuItem(MenuOperationsImpl.java:88)
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.web.selenium.SeleniumOperationsImpl.manageTestSuite(SeleniumOperationsImpl.java:185)
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.web.selenium.SeleniumOperationsImpl.generateTest(SeleniumOperationsImpl.java:140)
    at org.springframework.roo.addon.web.selenium.SeleniumCommands.generateTest(SeleniumCommands.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.roo.support.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy$1.callback(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:34)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProcessManager.doTransactionally(DefaultProcessManager.java:169)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProcessManager.execute(DefaultProcessManager.java:132)
    at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.execute(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:32)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:158)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.jline.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLineShell.java:200)
    at org.springframework.roo.shell.jline.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please type "development mode", press enter, then re-run the Selenium command and include the more detailed stack trace that follows?